# Request to merge or cleanup tags related to "system-monitoring"

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-request

I have recently added a tag wiki excerpt for [system-monitoring](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/system-monitoring) and found out that there are several tags that *might* be related to it and therefore *might* be considered as tag synonyms.

Such tags includes:

- [monitoring](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/monitoring)
- [resource-monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/resource-monitor)
- [process-monitoring](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/process-monitoring)
- [process-monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/process-monitor)
- [file-monitoring](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/file-monitoring)
- [disk-monitoring](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/disk-monitoring)

Maybe not all can be considered as synonyms but some are. I do not have enough reputation to suggest tag synonyms, so I trust people who has enough "**powers**" to do so will take care of this. Thank you.

Comment: [tag:process-monitor] may be referring to the [Sysinternals tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx). Same for [tag:resource-monitor] and the Windows built-in "Resource Monitor" tool. The rest, yea probably.